# Adding stick post button to edit post page

Tags: functions

Right now, posts can only be sticky through the quick edit panel.

Can I add a sticky checkbox to the post edit page?

Comment: the 'sticky' button is to be found under 'publish' -> 'visiblilty' on the 'edit post' page. do you need the button to be more prominent?

Comment: Damn! Never saw it before. Thx.